# Wolkenkit REST API for sending commands returns "Malformed command"

Tags: rest, wolkenkit

I am trying to use the REST API of Wolkenkit to send a command. I did not find any information in the docs, so i tried to find what is necessary by going through the source code and unit tests.

I am using [HTTPie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie) to do requests from the cli:

```
> http --verbose post https://local.wolkenkit.io:3500/v1/command id=12bf5b37-e0b8-42e0-8dcf-dc8c4aefc000 context:='{"name": "mycontext"}' aggregate:='{"name": "label", "id": "26c01e1f-abb8-42fa-82cf-60ca4a6bfbfa"}' name=create data:='{"label": "third"}' custom:='{}' metadata:='{"timestamp": "1504167240279", "correlationId": "12bf5b37-e0b8-42e0-8dcf-dc8c4aefc000", "causationId": "12bf5b37-e0b8-42e0-8dcf-dc8c4aefc000"}'

POST /v1/command HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 405
Content-Type: application/json
Host: local.wolkenkit.io:3500
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.9

{
    "aggregate": {
        "id": "26c01e1f-abb8-42fa-82cf-60ca4a6bfbfa",
        "name": "label"
    },
    "context": {
        "name": "mycontext"
    },
    "custom": {},
    "data": {
        "label": "third"
    },
    "id": "12bf5b37-e0b8-42e0-8dcf-dc8c4aefc000",
    "metadata": {
        "causationId": "12bf5b37-e0b8-42e0-8dcf-dc8c4aefc000",
        "correlationId": "12bf5b37-e0b8-42e0-8dcf-dc8c4aefc000",
        "timestamp": "1504167240279"
    },
    "name": "create"
}

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 30 Aug 2017 20:57:27 GMT
ETag: W/"12-2BIyYXjsDfNWq9+GqVAfSCeA8D4"
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Surrogate-Control: no-store
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY
X-Powered-By: Express
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Malformed command.
```

I used [wolkenkit console](https://console.wolkenkit.io/) to verify that the `aggregate.id` is correct. The `command.id` is just a random `uuid()`.

What did i wrong to get `Malformed command` as response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of wolkenkit.*

Internally, the commands are built using the [commands-events](https://github.com/thenativeweb/commands-events) module, which also is being used for verifying incoming commands.

The actual error comes from [tailwind](https://github.com/thenativeweb/tailwind/blob/ea8f7c0efd557172f202ec2c85a35ffbd408d0f2/lib/wires/api/http/v1/postCommand.js#L23-L27) which wolkenkit uses under the hood as base for an application that uses commands and events. Internally, this code [calls the `isWellformed` function](https://github.com/thenativeweb/tailwind/blob/ea8f7c0efd557172f202ec2c85a35ffbd408d0f2/lib/wires/api/http/v1/validateCommand.js#L6) of `commands-events`, which in turn [checks the schema](https://github.com/thenativeweb/commands-events/blob/c0935161d75d4765619d8efaac94fa74d17ec6f7/lib/Command.js#L80-L125) of the command.

From what I see everything seems to be fine, except that `metadata.timestamp` should be a `number`, not a `string`. I think that if you change this, then wolkenkit will accept your command happily.

Comment: Great, that works. Maybe it would be beneficial if the response includes the actual error message when validation fails.