# Public valid REST Api with wolkenkit.io

Tags: rest, wolkenkit

I am currently evaluating the framework "wolkenkit" [1] for using it in an application. Within this application I will have a user interface for tenant-based data management. Only authenticated users will have access to this application.

Additionally there should be a public REST API following common standards and being callable by public (tenant security done with submission of a tenant-based API Key within the request headers).

As far as I have found out, the wolkenkit REST API does not seem to fit these standards in forms of HTTP verbs.

But as wolkenkit at all appears to me as a really flexible and easy-to-use framework, I wonder how to basically implement such a public API.
May it be e.g. a valid approach to create an own web application which internally connects to the wolkenkit backend? What about the additional performance overhead then?

---

[1] https://www.wolkenkit.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49196843/1333873) of [mattwagl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2342332/mattwagl), I would like to point out a few things that you may be interested in.

First of all, since [wolkenkit](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit) is based on [CQRS](https://www.thenativeweb.io/blog/2017-12-14-14-17-ddd-and-co-part-7-cqrs/), the application has a separate API for writing and reading. That means, that if you send a command (whose intent is to change state) this goes to the write API. If you subscribe for events or run a query, this goes to the read API.

This again means, that if you send a command, it's up to the write side to respond to it. As the write side is not meant to return application state, all it says is basically: "Thanks, I have received the command." To get the actual result you have to wait for the appropriate event, which means subscribing to the read API.

In the [wolkenkit documentation](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/1.2.0/getting-started/understanding-wolkenkit/architecture/) there is a nice diagram which shows this in a clear way:

[image: wolkenkit architecture]

If you now add a separate REST API (which actually fulfills the requirements of REST), this means that you need to handle waiting for the result internally. In other words: Clients in wolkenkit are always meant to be asynchronous, REST is not. Hence it's your job to handle the asynchronous behavior of the wolkenkit APIs in your REST API. I think that this is the hardest part.

Once you have done this, you will have a synchronous REST API, and of course it will have *some* overhead. But I think that since its overhead is limited to passing through and translating network requests, it should be negligible.

Oh, and finally, there is another thing that you have to watch out for: Since REST as it was meant originally relies on the HTTP verbs to transport semantics, you need to map GET / POST / PUT / DELETE to the semantic commands of wolkenkit. As long as this can be done 1:1, everything's fine – problems start when there are multiple commands that (technically speaking) do an UPDATE.

*PS: I'm also one of the developers of [wolkenkit](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit).*

*PPS: However you are going to solve this, I would be highly interested to hear from you! It would be very great if you could share your experiences with us, as you are most probably not the last one with this idea. If you want to contact us, the easiest way would be via [Slack](http://slackin.wolkenkit.io/).*

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer (of course also thanks to @mattwagl). Btw: I stumpled upon wolkenkit by your dotnetpro series at the right point in time where I had to choose a new framework/environment for this new application, since my own (now more than six years old) CQRS framework (C#) does not include Event Sourcing and I hesitate to add it. Meanwhile, EventFlow is a hell of a framework - and there wolkenkit got me with that really clean and readable approach. Next I'll investigate on how to build up a complete docker environment. I'll keep you updated on slack, once the first api is done.

Comment: Wow, thanks  ... would love to discuss details with you, so I am very looking forward to you in Slack!

Answer (score 1):

wolkenkit applications can be accessed using an HTTP- and a Websocket-API. These APIs are both provided by the `tailwind` module that wolkenkit uses under the hood. In the tailwind repo you can find [a very simple documentation](https://github.com/thenativeweb/tailwind#accessing-tailwind-using-http) of the available HTTP routes.

You're right, the wolkenkit HTTP-API is not a classic REST-API. It's more RPC-style which in our experience is a good fit for applications. There are only 3 routes that your clients/tenants need to support: `/v1/command` (POST) is used for issuing commands. The commands you post should follow [the command schema](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/1.2.0/reference/data-structures/commands/). `/v1/events` (POST) can be used for streaming events to clients. These events will follow [the event schema](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/1.2.0/reference/data-structures/events/). Finally you have `/v1/read/:modelType/:modelName` (POST) to read models. You can simply [use HTTPie to test these routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45976397/wolkenkit-rest-api-for-getting-a-read-model-list-does-return-a-heartbeat-entry).

Authentication of these APIs is currently done using [OpenID-Connect](http://openid.net/connect/). There's [a very detailed article](https://auth0.com/blog/building-real-time-web-applications-using-wolkenkit/) on how to setup authentication using Auth0. I'm not quite sure if this fits your use-case but you could basically use any Authentication Service that follows this standard or that is able to issue [JWT](https://jwt.io/) tokens.

Finally you could also build your own JavaScript client-SDK that runs inside browsers by building a module that uses the [wolkenkit-client-js](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-client-js) under the hood. This SDK can just use the [same API as any other client](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/1.2.0/reference/building-a-client/connecting-to-an-application/) to connect to your application.

Hope this helps.

*PS: Please note that I am one of the authors of [wolkenkit](http://wolkenkit.io/).*

Comment: Understood so far. But that's the point - for some reason I do not want to expose the complete wolkenkit HTTP-API to the public, but instead only the read-side and within that only for a few resources.

So -MY application would be able to use the whole set of the API, but public access from outside of my app is restricted to a subset of it.

Would it - alternatively - be a valid approach, to have an own server side application (e.g. express), which internally connects to the wolkenkit read store?

Comment: Ok, I see. Seems like a valid approach to me. You would create some kind of a public API facade that would talk to your domain. If you do it using Node.js you can use the same client SDK that you would use in the browser. Another approach would be to restrict access to specific writeModel or readModel resources using authorization  https://docs.wolkenkit.io/1.2.0/reference/creating-the-write-model/configuring-authorization/ But if you would like more control on the design of the API the first approach let‘s you do that.